# How to position the whole site? css positioning problem

Tags: css

I am building this site - http://bellated.us.lt/

At some point the whole site went out from center positioning. I tried several ideas like putting margin: 0 auto; on body element and etc., but it didne help. Any ideas on how could I have it back to the center? thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like you've screwed up the nesting of your `div`s. For some reason, `#headercontainer` is containing everything else, which doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:940px;
}

#headercontainer {
    left:0;
}
```

If you loose the background image this way, give the background image to the html instead of the body.